# Why do my cross-references keep breaking?

Tags: adobe-indesign, cross-reference

I have a document, let's call it A, that consists mainly of a single text thread.
Somewhere in this thread, there's a cross reference to another chapter in the same thread, and it works fine.

I have a second document, lets' call it B, which is a variant of A.
B has different master pages and different paragraph/character styles, so I used the content collector/placer to link the text thread in A to the one in B.
A wise use of variables and conditional text took care of some smaller differences between the two threads, and that works fine too, except...

...well except for cross references. Cross references in B break, and when I set them right (to the corresponding paragraphs in B), cross references in A break, and so on in a cycle.

Why is this happening? How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you using Text Anchors and Hyperlinks?